# How can i add 3 buttons in the navigation bar and those buttons forward to other screens or view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Can somebody please tell me how i want to show 3 buttons in the navigation bar and it shows in all the screens or view controllers ? I want to make this in the single class and calling that class in all the view controllers. I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand what kind of question you can ask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Class named BaseVC. This will be your BaseViewController class. customise it and add 3 buttons to its's navigation bar programatically.

Now, extend this class in every other view controller and voila you are done.

Comment: But what about on selector function. How do i know which view controller use that fucntion

Comment: in your BaseVC class, add selectors to your navigation bar buttons. Implement their respective selector methods. Then wherever you extend this class in your ViewControllers, just override those methods ! :-) ...OOP rules dude !

Comment: I can add my own functionality

Comment: yeah you can , just over-ride those selector methods and they will work differently in each view controller where they are over-ridden.

Comment: Yo mention not ..your Welcome :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can add a container view that will be treated as a global view.

Comment: While this is correct, could you provide a code sample or further information? More complete answers help other users that may find this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Method which you can make use

NavButton class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol navProtocol : class {
    func button1()
    func button2()
    func button3()
}

class navButtons
{
    var navBtn1 = UIBarButtonItem()
    var navBtn2 = UIBarButtonItem()
    var navBtn3 = UIBarButtonItem()
    var navProtocolObj : navProtocol?

    static var shared = navButtons()

    func createButtonView() -> (UIBarButtonItem,UIBarButtonItem,UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        navBtn1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "btn1", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(navButtons.button1Action(sender:)))
        navBtn2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "btn2", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(navButtons.button2Action(sender:)))
        navBtn3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "btn3", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(navButtons.button3Action(sender:)))

        return (navBtn1,navBtn2,navBtn3)
    }


    @objc func button1Action(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        navProtocolObj?.button1()
    }
    @objc func button2Action(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        navProtocolObj?.button2()
    }
    @objc func button3Action(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        navProtocolObj?.button3()
    }
}
```

in Destination where you want all these to be performed

```
 import UIKit

class SourceVC: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let buttonAdded = navButtons.shared.createButtonView()
        navButtons.shared.navProtocolObj = self
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [buttonAdded.0,buttonAdded.1,buttonAdded.2]
    }

}

extension SourceVC : navProtocol {
    @objc func button1() {
        print("Button 1 Tapped")
    }

    func button2() {
        print("Button 2 Tapped")
    }

    func button3() {
        print("Button 3 Tapped")
    }    
}
```

Simulator Output Above:
[image]

Console Output Above:
[image]